# Attempt to modify registry from within a service fails in some situations?

Tags: c, windows, service

Again I am working on my Windows service and tried to modify the shell registry entry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon:Shell).

Initially I tried to do that in the ServiceControlHandler routine when the SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP arrives. That worked during testing by starting/stopping the service as long was is was logged on (I could see that the value changed). But when I going to shutdown/reboot the system, the value didn't changed.

Next I tried to do the same when user logs on or off (triggered by SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE in the ServiceControlHandler). To verify that may code should work in general I tried to modify the key in case of WTS_SESSTION_LOGOFF and WTS_SESSION_LOCK - I could see that the value changed after locking/unlocking the system. Once again, when I really logoff the value didn't change.

Do you have any ideas why this does not work?

Comment: Which `Reg...` functions fails and what error code does it return?

Comment: The service is coded using Qt 5.4, the value will be set by the QSettings::setValue() function. Currently I'm trying to find out if the code block will be reached anyhow (in case of "real" shut down / log off).

Comment: You realize that you don't get `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` during a system shutdown?  You get `SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN` instead - but only if you've set the `SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN` bit in your service status.

Comment: The tipp regarding setting SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN is helpful anyway. For some funny reason the problem does not occour any more at the moment. I could see that the WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF arrives and the code block is reached (and executed properly). I will come back to this if something changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen the behaviour sometimes, what sound like "it is sometimes coming too late". Not 100% sure if this is **THE** soulution, but I added a QSettings::sync() after writing the value, and the problem seemed to be gone.